# How to set 3 letter alpha country code based on country selection in HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set a country code by selecting a country in a form. I followed the below code to populate the country code on populating the country. Let me know if this below code is correct or not?

```js
// Countries
var country_arr = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antartica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Ashmore and Cartier Island", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burma", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Christmas Island", "Clipperton Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic of the", "Congo, Republic of the", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czeck Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Europa Island", "Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia", "French Southern and Antarctic Lands", "Gabon", "Gambia, The", "Gaza Strip", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Glorioso Islands", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Holy See (Vatican City)", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Howland Island", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Ireland, Northern", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Jan Mayen", "Japan", "Jarvis Island", "Jersey", "Johnston Atoll", "Jordan", "Juan de Nova Island", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, North", "Korea, South", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia, Former Yugoslav Republic of", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Man, Isle of", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States of", "Midway Islands", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Pitcaim Islands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romainia", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Helena", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Scotland", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and South Sandwich Islands", "Spain", "Spratly Islands", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Tobago", "Toga", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "Uruguay", "USA", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands", "Wales", "Wallis and Futuna", "West Bank", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe");

//country codes
var c_a = new Array();
c_a[0] = "";
c_a[1] = "AFG";
c_a[2] = "ALB";
c_a[3] = "DZA";
c_a[4] = "ASM";
c_a[5] = "AGO";
c_a[6] = "AIA";
c_a[7] = "ATA";
c_a[8] = "ATG";
c_a[9] = "ARG";
c_a[10] = "ARM";
c_a[11] = "ABW";
c_a[12] = "AUS";
c_a[13] = "AUS";
c_a[14] = "AUT";
c_a[15] = "AZE";
c_a[16] = "BHS";
c_a[17] = "BHR";
c_a[18] = "BGD";
c_a[19] = "BRB";
c_a[20] = "BLR";
c_a[21] = "BEL";
c_a[22] = "BLZ";
c_a[23] = "BEN";
c_a[24] = "BMU";
c_a[25] = "BTN";
c_a[26] = "BOL";
c_a[27] = "BIH";
c_a[28] = "BWA";
c_a[29] = "BRA";
c_a[30] = "VGB";
c_a[31] = "BRN";
c_a[32] = "BGR";
c_a[33] = "BFA";
c_a[34] = "BUR";
c_a[35] = "BDI";
c_a[36] = "KHM";
c_a[37] = "CMR";
c_a[38] = "CAN";
c_a[39] = "CPV";
c_a[40] = "CYM";
c_a[41] = "CAF";
c_a[42] = "TCD";
c_a[43] = "CHL";
c_a[44] = "CHN";
c_a[45] = "CXR";
c_a[46] = "IP";
c_a[47] = "CCK";
c_a[48] = "COL";
// <!-- -->
c_a[49] = "COM";
c_a[50] = "COD";
c_a[51] = "COG";
c_a[52] = "COK";
c_a[53] = "CRI";
c_a[54] = "CIV";
c_a[55] = "HRV";
c_a[56] = "CUB";
c_a[57] = "CYP";
c_a[58] = "CZE";
c_a[59] = "DNK";
c_a[60] = "DJI";
c_a[61] = "DMA";
c_a[62] = "DOM";
// <!-- -->
c_a[63] = "ECU";
c_a[64] = "EGY";
c_a[65] = "SLV";
c_a[66] = "GNQ";
c_a[67] = "ERI";
c_a[68] = "EST";
c_a[69] = "ETH";
c_a[70] = "EU";
c_a[71] = "FLK";
c_a[72] = "FRO";
c_a[73] = "FJI";
c_a[74] = "FIN";
c_a[75] = "FRA";
c_a[76] = "GUF";
c_a[77] = "PYF";
c_a[78] = "ATF";
c_a[79] = "GAB";
c_a[80] = "GMB";
c_a[81] = "GZ";
c_a[82] = "GEO";
c_a[83] = "DEU";
c_a[84] = "GHA";
c_a[85] = "GIB";
c_a[86] = "GO";
c_a[87] = "GRC";
c_a[88] = "GRL";
c_a[89] = "GRD";
c_a[90] = "GLP";
c_a[91] = "GUM";
c_a[92] = "GTM";
c_a[93] = "GGY";
c_a[94] = "GIN";
c_a[95] = "GNB";
c_a[96] = "GUY";
c_a[97] = "HTI";
c_a[98] = "HMD";
c_a[99] = "VAT";
c_a[100] = "HND";
c_a[101] = "HKG";
c_a[102] = "HQ";
c_a[103] = "HUN";
c_a[104] = "ISL";
c_a[105] = "IND";
c_a[106] = "IDN";
c_a[107] = "IRN";
c_a[108] = "IRQ";
c_a[109] = "IRL";
c_a[110] = "NIR";
c_a[111] = "ISR";
c_a[112] = "ITA";
c_a[113] = "JAM";
c_a[114] = "SJM";
c_a[115] = "JPN";
c_a[116] = "DQ";
c_a[117] = "JEY";
c_a[118] = "JQ";
c_a[119] = "JOR";
c_a[120] = "JU";
c_a[121] = "KAZ";
c_a[122] = "KEN";
c_a[123] = "KIR";
c_a[124] = "PRK";
c_a[125] = "KOR";
c_a[126] = "KWT";
c_a[127] = "KGZ";
c_a[128] = "LAO";
c_a[129] = "LVA";
c_a[130] = "LBN";
c_a[131] = "LSO";
c_a[132] = "LBR";
c_a[133] = "LBY";
c_a[134] = "LIE";
c_a[135] = "LTU";
c_a[136] = "LUX";
c_a[137] = "MAC";
c_a[138] = "MKD";
c_a[139] = "MDG";
c_a[140] = "MWI";
c_a[141] = "MYS";
c_a[142] = "MDV";
c_a[143] = "MLI";
c_a[144] = "MLT";
c_a[145] = "IMN";
c_a[146] = "MHL";
c_a[147] = "MTQ";
c_a[148] = "MRT";
c_a[149] = "MUS";
c_a[150] = "MYT";
c_a[151] = "MEX";
c_a[152] = "FSM";
c_a[153] = "MQ";
c_a[154] = "MDA";
c_a[155] = "MCO";
c_a[156] = "MNG";
c_a[157] = "MSR";
c_a[158] = "MAR";
c_a[159] = "MOZ";
c_a[160] = "NAM";
c_a[161] = "NRU";
c_a[162] = "NPL";
c_a[163] = "NLD";
c_a[164] = "ANT";
c_a[165] = "NCL";
c_a[166] = "NZL";
c_a[167] = "NIC";
c_a[168] = "NER";
c_a[169] = "NGA";
c_a[170] = "NIU";
c_a[171] = "NFK";
c_a[172] = "MNP";
c_a[173] = "NOR";
c_a[174] = "OMN";
c_a[175] = "PAK";
c_a[176] = "PLW";
c_a[177] = "PAN";
c_a[178] = "PNG";
c_a[179] = "PRY";
c_a[180] = "PRY";
c_a[181] = "PHL";
c_a[182] = "PCN";
c_a[183] = "POL";
c_a[184] = "PRT";
c_a[185] = "PRI";
c_a[186] = "QAT";
c_a[187] = "REU";
c_a[188] = "ROU";
c_a[189] = "RUS";
c_a[190] = "RWA";
c_a[191] = "SHN";
c_a[192] = "KNA";
c_a[193] = "LCA";
c_a[194] = "SPM";
c_a[195] = "VCT";
c_a[196] = "ASM";
c_a[197] = "SMR";
c_a[198] = "STP";
c_a[199] = "SAU";
c_a[200] = "SCT";
c_a[201] = "SEN";
c_a[202] = "SYC";
c_a[203] = "SLE";
c_a[204] = "SGP";
c_a[205] = "SVK";
c_a[206] = "SVN";
c_a[207] = "SLB";
c_a[208] = "SOM";
c_a[209] = "ZAF";
c_a[210] = "SGS";
c_a[211] = "ESP";
c_a[212] = "PG";
c_a[213] = "LKA";
c_a[214] = "SDN";
c_a[215] = "SUR";
c_a[216] = "SJM";
c_a[217] = "SWZ";
c_a[218] = "SWE";
c_a[219] = "CHE";
c_a[220] = "SYR";
c_a[221] = "TWN";
c_a[222] = "TJK";
c_a[223] = "TZA";
c_a[224] = "THA";
c_a[225] = "TTO";
c_a[226] = "TGO";
c_a[227] = "TKL";
c_a[228] = "TON";
c_a[229] = "TTO";
c_a[230] = "TUN";
c_a[231] = "TUR";
c_a[232] = "TKM";
c_a[233] = "TUV";
c_a[234] = "UGA";
c_a[235] = "UKR";
c_a[236] = "ARE";
c_a[237] = "GBR";
c_a[238] = "URY";
c_a[239] = "USA";
c_a[240] = "UZB";
c_a[241] = "VUT";
c_a[242] = "VEN";
c_a[243] = "VNM";
c_a[244] = "VGB";
c_a[245] = "WAL";
c_a[246] = "WLF";
c_a[247] = "WE";
c_a[248] = "ESH";
c_a[249] = "YEM";
c_a[250] = "SCG";
c_a[251] = "ZMB";
c_a[252] = "ZWE";

function populateCountryCode(countryElementId, countrycodeElementId) {

  var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;

  var countryCodeElement = document.getElementById(countrycodeElementId);

  countryCodeElement.length = 0;
  countryCodeElement.options[0] = new Option(countryCodeElement);
  countryCodeElement.selectedIndex = 0;

  var countrycode_arr = c_a[selectedCountryIndex];

  for (var i = 0; i < countrycode_arr.length; i++) {
    countryCodeElement.options[countryCodeElement.length] = new Option(countrycode_arr[i]);
  }
}

function populateCountryCodes(countryElementId, countrtycodeElementId) {
  // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
  var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
  countryElement.length = 0;
  countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '-1');
  countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
    countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
  }

  // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

  if (countrtycodeElementId) {
    countryElement.onchange = function() {
      populateCountryCode(countryElementId, countrtycodeElementId);
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Country</label>
  <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control" required></select>
  <input type="hidden" value="" class="form-control input-sm" id="country_code" name="country_code" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer: sorry, it was not meant to offend (and I tried not to make such word offensive, by passive construct of the phrase). I was commenting how people would react (I assume the list was created programmatically).  In any case I repeat the other part of comment: the two array are misaligned (Afghanistan has index 0 in first, and 1 in the second array).

Comment: And sorry also to you @shravaniKalluri. I didn't want to offend you.

Comment: @Giacomo: thanks. Your remark has now been deleted, so I suggest you delete all your related comments, and the matter can be considered closed. I was just giving feedback as a native English speaker - I accept that you did not mean offence, but the non-offensive meaning did not really come through clearly. I will delete this comment tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to set a country code by selecting a country in a form

In a `<select>` dropdown menu, each `<option>` will have a `value` attribute.

You can use the three-letter code as your value for each `<option>`.

**Working Example:**

```js
/* GRAB SELECT ELEMENT */
var countryMenu = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];

/* FUNCTION TO SHOW THREE LETTER CODE */
function showSelectedCountryCode() {
    console.log('You have selected: ' + countryMenu.value);
}

/* ATTACH EVENT-BASED FUNCTION TO SELECT ELEMENT */
countryMenu.addEventListener('change', showSelectedCountryCode, false);
```

```html
<select>
<option value="">Please Select Country...</option>
<option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="ALB">Albania</option>
<option value="DZA">Algeria</option>
<option value="ASM">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AGO">Angola</option>
</select>
```